# How to sharpen more div border using CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a div in moon shape, like this:

[image]

What I got to make was this:

```css
.half-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
   
    background-color: gold;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```

Is possible fine tune more with CSS?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS only like this, if you want to make this shape use SVG , it will be easy and sharp

Comment: Thank you for answer me, sorry my ignorance, when you say SVG, I create a image and use it as a div background?

Comment: @TMoraes: yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some rotation you can do it:

```css
.half-circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.half-circle::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width: 2000px;  /* this need to be as big as possible to cover a big area */
  height: 2000px; /* this need to be the same as width */
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  /* adjust the -65% and the 75deg to control the height 
     don't touch the other
  */
  transform: translate(-50%, -65%) rotateX(75deg) rotate(45deg);
  background-color: gold;
  border-radius:0 0 10% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```